# Removed "Question closed"-message should be shown in edit review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I just had this edited question come up for review

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1274058

It looks like the editor made a small change and added a question of his own. But he also removed the system message that the question was closed as a duplicate.

This is seen in the revision history here

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14143933/revisions

but is not visible in the edit review. So, of course, the edit was approved!

I propose that *all* edits to a post are shown in the edit review. :-)

---

Apparently all *proposed* edits are shown, but in that case the approved edit is all that should be applied to the post and nothing more.

I now see that this is somewhat similar to earlier "Who did the edit?" questions, where some edits show up on the wrong user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit suggestion was made *before* the question was closed:

- Suggested edit: 2013-01-03 17:26:02Z
- Question closed: 2013-01-03 17:26:25Z

In other words, the suggestion was made without the automated "Question closed" message present in the post.

The real problem, then, is that the Community edit should either have *cancelled* that suggested edit, or should have altered (base for) the suggested edit as well.

Comment: Ah, I do most of my visits here on an iPad and miss out on the mouse-over effects. (Should consider another feature-request on that :-).