# Has the automatic linking to exact duplicates been broken?

Tags: bug, status-declined, duplicate-questions

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14226080/179910) was just closed as an exact duplicate, but doesn't seem to contain the usual link back to the question it duplicates. Has this been changed intentionally, or has a bug cropped up, what exactly?

Comment: It's in the revision history...

Comment: No idea what happened here, specifically, but I re-saved Community user's revision so the link shows up properly now.

Comment: @AnnaLear: But Community's revision somehow had an old revision of the post, missing some of the OP's data. ;P

Comment: @animuson Oops, my bad. Thanks. :) How many high-rep users does it take to fix a bot's mistake...? (This is why we have captchas, people! Robots can't be trusted!)

Comment: I think I remember this happening somewhat recently. The user starts to edit the question prior to the community user adding the dup question content; therefore, when the user finishes their edit they will remove the duplicate question content added to the question while they were editing it.

Comment: Ah -- thanks Anna. Hadn't thought of colliding edits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removed "Question closed"-message should be shown in edit review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161377/removed-question-closed-message-should-be-shown-in-edit-review-queue). The question can be closed while the edit is still in review. It will then be applied incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've removed adding text to question bodies entirely for now.  Who knows what the future holds, though :P

<sub>It was a right good bug, though; glad I don't have to fix it now!</sub>

Comment: For future reference: this was changed as part of [changes to “close as duplicate”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux), in which the "This question already has an answer here" box was introduced.