# Unneeded encoding of html entities in code in title in duplicate link

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

There was `&lt;` `&gt;` in stub from Community user in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9763327/4):

Now it's edited out by me so link is to revision from Community

Comment: They normally *are* needed. The problem here is that someone tried to use inline code formatting in the title, which isn't supported in titles. When the title was inserted into the body of the post, the inline code formatting magically started working, which made escaping unnecessary. I don't know what the fix for this would be—stripping inline code formatting from titles when auto-inserting them into a question?

Comment: @CodyGray, it would be simple and efficient. But it's also possible to remove them automatically from titles on save or fairly parse titles where ` exists on stub generation

Comment: Note that Community's edit was more than a year old. Things might have been fixed by now.

Comment: @Arjan: Considering Community doesn't edit the post anymore. ;)

Comment: Actually, stripping backticks from titles on submission might not be a bad idea. I see them misused there relatively often, serving absolutely no purpose but to clutter things up. Can anyone think of a legitimate usage of backticks in a title?

Comment: Ah, animuson is right: this is no longer an issue as [no duplicate links are inserted into the Markdown anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162061/has-the-automatic-linking-to-exact-duplicates-been-broken/166901#166901).